# How many subsets of four numbers from the set are there in which the sum of the largest and smallest number in the subset is 15?

Tags: combinatorics

How many subsets of four numbers from the set $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14$ are there in which the sum of the largest and smallest number in the subset is $15$?

The answer is: $C(10,2)+C(8,2)+C(6,2)+C(4,2)+C(2,2)$

I have no idea where these numbers are coming from? Can someone please help me to understand what the solution is doing. The choose $2$ is especially confusing because it says subsets of $4$ numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the smallest and largest numbers are 2 and 13, then the other two numbers are chosen from 3, 4,..., 12 (10 numbers).  If the smallest and largest are 3 and 12, then...

Answer (score 1):

Let the the set is S={a,b,c,d} and it is given that $a+d=15$.

Now fisrt choose the smallest number in the given set of 13 integers.It

is 2 and according to 2 the largest number is $15-2=13$. Now fix 2 and 13 in the

place of a and d.Now we have S={2,b,c,13} and now choose b,c from the residue

set (besides 14){3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}. The total number of ways doing this $\implies\;{10\choose2}$.The

strategy is to choose the minimum and accordingly maximum will be chosen.Then

Count the number of ways from the residue set={minimum,...,maximum}.Then add

them for each minimum or maximum case, then you will have the answer of your

required question.